# How do you return an array in a method?

Tags: java, arrays, return

I'm unsure of how to return an array of strings. Originally, I populated the array with a for loop then just converted it to a string using toString(). I am not allowed to change the return type so I would like to know how do you return the string array? I tried returning the array, but it returned the memory address. Here's the code:

```
public String getValues(int start, int end) 
{
    String[] values  = new String[end+1];
    for(int i=0;i<values.length;i++)
    {
       if(i % ham != 0 && i % spam != 0)
       {
           values[i]=Integer.toString(i);
       }
       else if(i % ham == 0 && i % spam != 0)
       {
           values[i]= word2;
       }
       else if(i % ham != 0 && i % spam == 0)
       {
           values[i]= word3;
       }
       else if(i % ham == 0 && i % spam == 0)
       {
           values[i]= word1;
       }
    }
    String[] result= java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(values,2,end+1);
    String str1= java.util.Arrays.toString(result);
    return str1;
}
```

I am only allowed to edit this class. My method has to return the String array with all of the elements in it. No println, print, or anything of that sort. I thought that just returning the array would work, but I just get the address. I don't know what the problem is.I changed the return type to String[] and took out the toString() and just returned result. Still getting the address of the array, to be specific this:    [Ljava.lang.String;@391673

Answer (score 3):

#### You must change the type of the return value to `String[]`.

```java
public String[] getValues(int start, int end) {
  // ...
  return result;
}
```

Then you can print the results as such:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String[] values = new MyClass().getValues(1, 2);
  String valuesString = java.util.Arrays.toString(values);
  System.out.println("VALUES: " + valuesString);
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it returned the address of the array instead of the elements. Returns this exactly: 
[Ljava.lang.String;@391673

Comment: @dzag30: perhaps you tried to print the returned array directly and misinterpreted the result?  Instead try printing it via `Array.toString` per your example.

Comment: I used Array.toString originally, but this converts it to a String so i would have to change the return type

Comment: @maerics: that's why java's array declaration as `int foo[]` is that confusing, it should be `int[] foo`, after all `int[]` is the type, not `int`.

Comment: I would print the results as you suggested, but I am not allowed to edit the main method, it was provided in a separate class which we may not touch.

Comment: @dzag30: it sounds like there are more constraints to your problem than are described in your question - consider including the relevant details to get better answers.